# In Selenium, content textbox is getting erased automatically

Tags: java, selenium, textbox, webdriver

I am trying to write text in the textbox using the below code in selenium:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("name_value")).sendKeys("abc");
```

However, it write to the textbox, but once it moves out of that input box, the content gets erased.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

this most likely has to do with javascript events in the application.

it's not selenium's fault, but rather how the app retrieves keystrokes.

look around, i'm sure you'll find something bound to on keydown/keypress,keyup and some validation method.  if the validation method doesn't finish in time, it will most likely clear the text field.

You have a few solutions -

1. Use the `JavaScriptExecutor` to take out the key events
2. Use `Actions` rather than sendKeys() and put a timeout between every keypress.

something like (pseudo-code):

```
void sendKeys(String keys) {
  for (Char key : keys.chars()) {
    Actions.press(key)
    Thread.sleep(500)
  }
}
```

3. use `sendKeys()` multiple times.  try 3 times, and if it's not set still, try another solution.